# Can't use defined object further down?

Tags: qt, qml

Why can't I use the id name for Checkbox further down?  Am I missing something... thx

" Cannot assign to non-existent property "myCheckbox""

```
               CheckBox {
                    id:myCheckbox
                    width: 50
                    height: 50
                    backingVisible: false
                    checkable: true



                    onClicked: {
                        table.sw[rowIndex][index + table.bs] = myCheckbox.checked;
                    }
                }

                myCheckbox.checked: { //ERROR : why can't I use myCheckbox here?
                    false;//reset the recently checked
                }
```

Comment: You're trying to use declarative syntax to do something imperative ("reset the recently checked"). Did you mean something like `myCheckbox.onChecked: { myCheckbox.checked = false; }` ?

Comment: tried something like this... can't seem to go out of scope.  Not sure why...

Comment: try `property bool checkBoxChecked: myCheckbox.checked; onCheckBoxChecked: { ... }`